# Loop through a dataframe to change the value of a vector

Tags: r, loops

I need to create a loop through a dataframe that changes the value of a variable to "NA" if it is currently blank.

I created the following loop and it does not change the values of the vector in the dataframe.

```
for( i in Migration_data){ 
    if(Migration_data$Tag.Version ==""){
    Migration$Tag.Version[i] = "NA"
 }
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't need a loop,  `is.na(Migration_data$Tag.Version) <- Migration_data$Tag.Version==''`

Comment: Also, when replacing, remove the quotes around `"NA"` to get actual `NA` values.  `"NA"` will give you a character string which will fail with `is.na()` testing

Comment: That did it, thanks!  Still new to R.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a for loop. Try:

```
Migration_data[Migration_data$Tag.Version == "", "Tag.Version"] <- NA
```